# Modx - Getresource filter by TV date

Tags: modx-revolution

I am trying to use getResources to filter based on a date-type TV.
I ant to create a filter that allows me to either show Future events and Past events.

TVname = `voucherdate`

**What I have done is:**

Create a current date snippet with the following:

```
<?php
return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Then I created the following getResource:

**Current events**

```
[[!getResources?
  ...
  &tvFilters=`voucherdate>=[[curDate]]`
]]
```

**Past events**

```
 [[!getResources?
      ...
      &tvFilters=`voucherdate<<[[curDate]]`
    ]]
```

But it does not seem to be working. I have tested to se where the sniper works by calling only `[[curDate]]` in a template and that shows the current date.

Could anyone offer some advice.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

all your template variables are store as strings, so you are going to have to do some string comparison..... which is probably not going to work in the getresources call...

best thing to do is to pass the date string value to a snippet and do your date comparison there, something like:

```
[[!getResources? ...
&tvFilters=`[[!DateCompare? &date=`[[*voucherdate]]` &range=`future|past` ]]  == 'true']]
]]
```

convert your dates to epoch or something in the DateCompare snippett and return true or false...  then getResources ~should~ return the correct resources ... I think, not tested... I con't think of an easier way off the top of my head. UNLESS you want to store your dates as an epoch value initially... [that would be better anyway] then your string comparison you were trying would 'just work'

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for the comment. I should of mentioned I know nothing about PHP, I kind of jsut stringed those bits together from various resources. Anyway you can help me correct the snipper